# MySql Identity with MVC 5

Tags: mysql, asp.net, identity

I created a new MVC 5 application with .NET Framework 4.6.1 with VS 2017.

I'm using a MySql database and I want the baked in Identity functionality to work with this version of my project.

However, I can only find this older example which does work if I create a 4.5.1 project even using VS 2017.  I haven't been lucky in finding other solutions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider

Is there another way to implement this in MVC 5 without having to revert to 4.5.1?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating a new MVC 4 project in 4.5.1, making the changes in described in the link below and then upgrading my project's framework to 4.6.1 and everything works as expected.

If a solution comes along for MVC 5+ that anyone is aware of please post an answer.